# How to check if a platform supports FontFace API?

Tags: javascript, font-face

Can I check if a platform supports the FontFace API as below?

```
if(window.FontFace || window.webkitFontFace) {
     //...
}
```

Or should not I check for the existence of "window.webkitFontFace"?

**Note:** I am wondering if it can support Javascript's FontFace API and not CSS's @font-face, although the FontFace API uses the CSS @font-face.

Comment: `@font-face` is different from FontFace, not really, but a platform can support `@font-face` CSS and not Javascript API FontFace?

Comment: If `FontFace` is not supported, then it (normally) is `undefined`. The check for `webkitFontFace` serves no purpose though, so I'd remove that part.

Comment: @Stijn Okay, thank you, create an answer, which will be much better than the mistake of the answer below. Hes do not read the question right and are already marked as duplicate, there should be a penalty for this precipitation too, because it always happens, too boring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `FontFace` is not supported, it is `undefined` (unless custom JS sets the `window.FontFace` variable for some reason). So the first part of your proposed code is fine. Checking for `webkitFontFace` serves no purpose and can be removed.

```
if (window.FontFace) {
    console.log("supported");
} else {
    console.log("not supported");
}
```

The code above returns `supported` on the latest Firefox, and it returns `unsupported` on the latest Internet Explorer.